# How to add a drop shadow to custom thumbImage in UIKit UiSlider?

Tags: ios, xcode, uikit, uislider

I have created a customised vertical slider (for audio mixing applications) based on UISlider in UIKit, and I would like to add a drop shadow to the custom thumb image. There looks to have been the ability to do this in earlier versions of Xcode, but not with more recent versions. Any advice very welcome!

Comment: Cant the shadow be part of thumb image itself? will it not be much more easier option to with?

Comment: Thanks Sandeep, but the drop shadow will offset the centre of the thumb image, which means that the offset has to be known for the thumb image to be correctly centred. It also means that the limits of travel of the thumb image along the slider will also be affected.